# Path(Trajectory) of four missiles launched by battle ships at the vertices of a square.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

PROBLEM STATEMENT:

The positions of four battle ships on the ocean are such that the ships form the vertices of a square of length L = 2l. At some instant each ship fires a missile that directs its motion steadily toward the missile on its right. Assuming that the four missiles fly horizontally and with the same speed, find the path of the missile shot from each of the ships.

ATTEMPTED SOLUTION:

I thought this problem was similar to the classic mice pursuit problem and as I had already derived the following relation for an N-gon I used it to get the trajectory of the missiles.

$r(\theta$) = $r_0e^{-\theta\tan(\frac{\pi}{N})}$   -(1)

In this case $N = 4$, this leads to (1) becoming

$r(\theta$) = $r_0e^{-\theta}$ -(2)

Now, I'm certain that (2) is the required equation that describes the trajectory of the missiles. However, the answer provided in my book is

$x-l$ $=$ $r_0cos(\theta)$ and
$y-l$ $=$ $r_0sin(\theta)$

To clear my confusions, I searched online and the solution I found online (which yields the same answer as my book) seems to be valid.

Can someone please inform whether my solution is correct? And if my solution is correct can I arrive at the books answers from my answer by changing the polar coordinates of my answer to cartesian coordinates?

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the solution you found online? It seems wrong to me.

Comment: The solution was posted on Chegg. I don't have a subscription though. It was one of the sample solutions on it. https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/positions-four-battle-ships-ocean-ships-form-vertices-square-length-l-2l-instant-ship-fire-q23733318

Comment: OK, what made their answer seem wrong is you wrote $r_0$ (which is a constant) in equations where they write $r,$ which is a non-constant distance for which they give a rather complicated formula.

Comment: On further inspection I still think their answer is wrong. The correct answer is a logarithmic spiral (like you found). Their answer blows up at $\theta=\pi/2 + n\pi.$

Comment: Oh I assumed that the $r$ they used was a constant. Thanks a lot. Would you mind giving me the expression for $r$ in their equation?

Comment: It's just before $x-l \equiv r\cos\theta$ on the page you linked to. Look for $r = $ with a really ugly formula on the right side of the $=$ sign.

Comment: Yeah I just saw it. Thank you for taking time to clear out my confusions.

Comment: The $x - l = r\cos\theta$ formulas are just the conversion from polar to cartesian coordinates, translated so that the center of the square is at $(l,l).$ Your formula gives polar coordinates where the center of the square is at the origin, which makes more sense in my opinion. But if your book says the lower left corner is at $(0,0)$ then I suppose that's where it is.